# Optimize query performance for last week's trending titles based on views

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a query that takes ~160 seconds that looks at recorded user views for a given related title and returns those with the most views from the past week.

```
SELECT issue_types.name AS issue_type_name, titles.name AS title_name, titles.primary_issue_id, titles.id, title_views.title_id, COUNT(title_views.title_id) AS views,
CASE WHEN titles.id = 14313 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 1
WHEN titles.id = 268 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 100
WHEN titles.id = 1331 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 400
WHEN titles.id = 12722 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 200
WHEN titles.id = 4605 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 200
WHEN titles.id = 13365 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 500
WHEN titles.id = 3714 THEN COUNT(title_views.title_id) - 500
ELSE views
END AS calcViews FROM titles
LEFT JOIN issues ON issues.id = titles.primary_issue_id
LEFT JOIN title_views ON title_views.title_id = titles.id
LEFT JOIN issue_types ON issue_types.id = issues.issue_type_id
WHERE titles.deleted = FALSE AND titles.primary_issue_id IS NOT NULL
AND title_views.created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY title_views.title_id, issue_types.name, titles.name, titles.primary_issue_id, titles.id
ORDER BY calcViews DESC, titles.name ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Here's some info on the `title_views` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `title_views` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_client_title_views_titles` (`title_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_client_title_views_titles` FOREIGN KEY (`title_id`) REFERENCES `titles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `title_views_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17978207 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Rows: 2,442,396

Data    133.7   MiB
Index   113.2   MiB
Total   246.9   MiB

Here's info on `titles`:

```
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `needs_indexing` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `primary_issue_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_titles_issues` (`primary_issue_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_titles_issues` FOREIGN KEY (`primary_issue_id`) REFERENCES `issues` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24010 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Rows: 23,500

Data    2.5 MiB
Index   2   MiB
Total   4.5 MiB

When removing the check for if the view was created in the past week, it goes down to 10 seconds which still isn't great but much better than the current.

I'm not sure how to better optimize this other than a weekly cache of the queries as I'm no DB Admin but it's obviously causing extremely poor UX and I need to optimize it or find a better way to do what it's trying to do.

Comment: Can you please execute the `explain <query>` (by writing explain before your query and executing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is several possible approaches to optimization problems in mysql

Here is how i would try to optimize the query

1. Add index on `view_counts.created`
2. Rewrite the query to 1st gather counts depending on the date, and then to it join the data which will speed up data lookup and matching.
3. Add compound index on (`primary_issue_id`, `deleted`) and also on (`delete`, `primary_issue_id`)

Then i would rewrite the query to this:

```sql
select 
    counts.title_id,
    issue_types.name AS issue_type_name,
    titles.name AS title_name,
    titles.primary_issue_id 
    CASE 
      WHEN counts.title_id = 14313 THEN counts.c -1
      WHEN counts.title_id = 268 THEN counts.c - 100
      WHEN counts.title_id = 1331 THEN counts.c - 400
      WHEN counts.title_id = 12722 THEN counts.c - 200
      WHEN counts.title_id = 4605 THEN counts.c - 200
      WHEN counts.title_id = 13365 THEN counts.c - 500
      WHEN counts.title_id = 3714 THEN counts.c - 500
    ELSE counts.c as view_counts
from 
  (
    select
      tv.title_id, count(tv.title_id) as c
    from
      title_views as tv 
    where 
      tv.created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    group by tv.id
  ) as counts
LEFT JOIN issues ON issues.id = titles.primary_issue_id
left join issue_types ON issue_types.id = issues.issue_type_id
WHERE
   titles.deleted = FALSE
     AND
   titles.primary_issue_id IS NOT NULL

-- here just add groupings and ordering (i dont know which setting you are using)
```

4. I would execute this query prefixing it with `explain` word, to get information how mysql sees the optimizations for the query (there should not be any full table scans - would be great if you could attach the explain output for this query)
5. In this explain output used indexes are to be written - after that i would remove not used one from point 3.

Comment: This is almost perfect! Just the group by in the subquery needed to be changed to tv.title_id instead of id. Thank you so much sir! Kudos!